# HTTP POST request in AngularJS returns 403

Tags: javascript, angular, http, post

I'm building a web application in Angular. I am trying to send a POST request to a REST API but I get 403. If I send a curl request in the cmd it works perfectly fine.

Here is the code in TypeScript:

```
   let header=new HttpHeaders().set('accept','application/json')
   header=header.set('X-AbiliSense-API-Key','18306df7-3fde-49a1-9bef-6ad7a9d83e7f')
   this.NewPost=this.http.post('https://api.abilisense.com/v1/api/registerDevice',{header:header});
```

in cmd:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.abilisense.com/v1/api/registerDevice" -H "accept: application/json" -H "X-AbiliSense-API-Key: 18306df7-3fde-49a1-9bef-6ad7a9d83e7f"//this works
```

[image]

Comment: Is it supposed to be a `header` property, or should it be `headers`?

Comment: @Jacob what is the difference ?

Comment: it's `headers` property, which version are you using?

Comment: @Aravind swagger "version": "0.0.1",

Comment: @louayjaber: the difference is that `header` isn't a valid config option whereas `headers` is, unless `this.http` points to something unusual. I suspect because you have the property name wrong, no headers are being sent. To me, this is one of the many reasons why TypeScript is useful.

Comment: @Jacob well I tried to send the headers in the URL but it still failed. this.http points to HttpClient imported from '@angular/common/http'

Comment: Do you see the proper headers being sent in the network tab of your developer tools? And is it failing the same way as before?

Comment: the headers are shown in the request payloads as lazy update @Jacob

Comment: @Jacob I edited my question I added an image of the headers on the network

Comment: Looks like you're sending the headers as part of the payload, not as part of the HTTP options. I'm not familiar with the HTTP service, but you should consult the API docs. From a cursory glance, the http options are the third parameter; the second is the post body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Jacob explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60955965/http-post-request-in-angularjs-returns-403#comment107844799_60955965), the second parameter of [`post()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L2078) is the request body, whereas the headers must be passed in the third parameter.

Add `null` as the second parameter, and use `headers` (not `header`) in the third parameter:

```
let headers = ...

this.NewPost = this.http.post('https://api.abilisense.com/v1/api/registerDevice', null, {headers: headers});
```